# Perl JSON validation function

Tags: json, perl, debian

I'm using the Perl module, JSON when handling JSON data in a perl script.

I was looking to use `valid_json` from the `JSON::Parser` module, however it looks as though the version i'm using, 2.53 has deprecated this. 
Reading the docs for 2.53, i cannot see any validation functions.

Am i just to rely on `decode_json`, & `encode_json` returns to tell me that a JSON string is invalid?

Comment: There is also https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::JSON which has an `is_valid_json` function, but it creates a Test::Harness and prints TAP output. However, you can borrow its functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may `decode_json` in eval and see if it will throw an exception.

Comment: I didn't use eval as it was suggested that the footprint is abit big when using it, however i did use the method of catching the exception using `Try::Tiny`. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple json validation function available (yet).

One way to do so is like following:

```
try {
    decode_json_utf8($json_string)
} catch($e) {
    print("invalid json. Error: $e");
}
```

Another way to achieve this is:

```
eval {decode_json_utf8($json_string)}; 

print "json error" if $@;
```